# Android ImageView Full Screen

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to draw a circle on ImageView, so far I can do it using bitmap and setOnTouchListener of the ImageView but it always put it in wrong place, so what I need is : make ImageView take all the screen so that point(0,0) match the point(0,0) of the device screen.

[image: what I got as result for now]

this is my activity layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.ghoster.second.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/test4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How do you calculate X,Y ?
Post the code where you decide where to draw...

Comment: use `android:scaletype="fitXY"` in imageview. Also in your `RelativeLayout` use `match_parent` for both `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
android:scaletype="FIT_XY"
```

You can also use for latest API

```
android:scaletype="fitXY"
```

in the imageview